# SQL: Qué significa 'stage'?

Tags: mysql

A ver si me podéis ayudar con esto:

Estoy actualizando código, es decir, tengo código viejo que tengo que reescribir, y es algo así `select distinct parameter stage from table where...`. Este es un comando SQL a ejecutar en una base de datos embebido en c#.net, en una librería.

Mi pregunta es qué es `stage`? no hay `,` después de `parameter` así que no puede ser otro parámetro. El código, hasta donde sé, no da problemas, así que supongo que estará bien. He buscado y no es una palabra reservada `Keyword`, así que estoy totalmente perdida.

La base de datos original era SQL compact pero ahora va a ser otra (SQLite).

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para este caso `parameter stage` puede que la equivalencia te sea más familiar `parameter AS stage` la palabra `AS` se utiliza para renombrar una columna o tabla, seria equivalente a tener un alias, esto es muy común cuando tienes campos que contiene valores genéricos y quieres asignar un nombre de columna más específico según el contexto del SQL por ejemplo `SELECT comunicacion  AS correo  FROM envio WHERE tipo = 'correo'` ó  `SELECT comunicacion  AS telefono FROM envio WHERE tipo = 'telefono'`, en este caso un tabla tiene varios tipos de comunicación y se cambia el nombre de la columna para darle mas sentido, tu tambien lo puedes probar con cualquier SELECT que ya estés ejecutando en tu base de datos.

Comment: Gracias! conozco el uso de as, pero no sabía que podía omitirse en la query

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido la información @IriaPoncelaBlanco, imagine que lo sabrías pero es bueno siempre responder con una explicación para ayudar a otros miembro que tenga la misma duda.